# No matching provisioning profiles found for xcode8,

Tags: provisioning-profile, xcode8, ios-provisioning

1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
    /var/folders/bc/2b1r9_015p726bd9jqjls91r0000gn/T/75C9788F-B9DE-4AF6-8396-7570A3825B13/1144919352.itmsp -

> Error Messages:      ERROR ITMS-90034: "Missing or invalid signature.
>   The bundle 'Bundle ID' at bundle path 'Payload/App name.app' is not
>   signed using an Apple submission certificate."

Comment: Can you please help me any one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a distribution certificate to upload a build for distribution. You can have a distribution certificate by enrolling in Apple Developer program w/o which you would not be able to do so.

This is exactly what your error message is trying to say.

Read this for more information: https://developer.apple.com/programs/